# Integral of power series over a region

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, power-series, improper-integrals

Let $$ F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^ \infty a_nx^n$$ where the power series converges in a neighborhood of the origin. Compute $$ \mu(F)= \sup \{ \delta > 0 : \text{there exist} \  \epsilon > 0  \ \text{such that} \ \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon |F(x)|^{- \delta}dx < \infty\}$$ where the integrals are interpreted as improper Riemann integrals if $F(0)=0$

I think 
we can divide this into two cases where one is when $F(0) = 0$ and when $F(0)$ is non zero. 
For $F(0)$ is non zero and $ 0< \epsilon<R$ where R is the radius of convergence the integral converges and using continuity  we can get $ \mu (F) = \infty$

We also have to do for $F(0) = 0$

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe try a few easy examples of $F(x)$ to give you an idea?

Comment: we can divide this into two cases where one is when F(0) = 0 and when F(0) is non zero. 
For F(0) is non zero and $\epsilon<R$ where R is the radius of convergence the integral converges and we can get $ \mu (F) = \infty$

Comment: In your question, you assumed $F(0) = 0$. Try $F(x)=x$... What is $\mu$ for that $F$? e.g., $$\int_0^1 x^{-1/2}\, dx$$ converges, right?

Comment: Sorry - I had misread your question - so please read my suggestion with "assuming $F(0)=0$"... For the  $F(0)\not = 0$ case, your idea is right, but you probably also want to choose an $\epsilon$ so that $F(x)$ is bounded away from $0$ for $|x|< \epsilon$...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For the case $F(0)=0$ (if the function $F$ is not $0$) you can write $F(x)=x^mG(x)$ for a $G$ such that $G(0)\not =0$(and of radius of convergence $R$). Hence you can find an $\varepsilon$, $0<\varepsilon<R$, such that if $|x|\leq \varepsilon$, we have 
$$c=\frac{|G(0)|}{2}\leq |G(x)|\leq \frac{3|G(0)|}{2} =d$$

Now in $[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$, you have
$$c|x|^m\leq |F(x)|\leq d|x|^m $$